# How to set up cron job to run php page with pear mail

Tags: php, cron, html-email, pear

I have a php page `automatic/emails.php` that when clicked will run several functions to output a Pear Mail email to applicable users. It works when I manually go to the page. How do I run a cron job through my cPannel to have it run every morning?

I understand the `* * * * * *` but I don't know what command to use or if I have to alter my php page. I have tried:

```
 30 17 8 * * lynx -source http://example.com/auto/emails.php
```

and

```
 30 17 8 * * lynx http://example.com/auto/emails.php`
```

and

```
 30 17 8 * * wget http://example.com/auto/emails.php
```

I have included my email for the server to send me an email when the cron job runs, but nothing has happened. The time was from when I tried it earlier today.

Any help is appreciated. I've tried to research this but can't find anything simple enough to start with. Thanks!

Comment: Don't put the url from your site, put the path of your script (for example /var/www/public/script.php)

Comment: if it doesn't require some info from the web browser, you can call it directly with php: `php emails.php`

Answer (score 0):

I found this site that really explained the basics, which is what I was looking for. https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/php/run-php-scripts-from-cron-jobs

I ended up using `curl http://example.com/script.php` but the site really helped.